# Does Datastore (Firestore in Datastore Mode) store entities in order by their key/name?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

When a write is performed, does the database write the entities in some kind of order by their key?

For example, if I have written following keys (intentionally keeping the `name` (1, 7, 3) out of sequence):

```
["A", "1"]
["A", "7"]
["A", "3"]
```

Would a query on the Kind `A` with no filters or ordering return the results as:

```
["A", "1"]
["A", "3"]
["A", "7"]
```

Maybe even more to the point if my keys contained a timestamp (milliseconds as the name):

```
["UserSession", "e4facf67-969d-46f5-b922-390f61beac0a", "UserRecord", "1597872201000"]
["UserSession", "e4facf67-969d-46f5-b922-390f61beac0a", "UserRecord", "1597872207000"]
["UserSession", "e4facf67-969d-46f5-b922-390f61beac0a", "UserRecord", "1597872203000"]
```

Would a query on

```
("UserRecord").hasAncestor(["UserSession", "e4facf67-969d-46f5-b922-390f61beac0a"])
```

return the objects sorted by their name (aka timestamp in milliseconds)?

- 1597872201000
- 1597872203000
- 1597872207000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode does store entities in key order.  You can see this from the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#keys) document which says:

> If you assign your own manual numeric ID or custom name to the entities you create, do not use monotonically increasing values

> If an application generates large traffic, such sequential numbering could lead to hotspots that impact Datastore mode latency.

Comment: So the record's location from above isn't `["UserSession", "e4facf67-969d-46f5-b922-390f61beac0a", "UserRecord", "1597872201000"]`.  In that case the UUID would help to keep collisions to the same **UUID+timestamp**, the record is really located at `["UserRecord", "1597872201000"]` with some fancy Ancestor stuff that can happen. But **Kind+Timestamp** (monotonically increasing value) is really its ID  and would for sure yield collisions under high use. So a key `[A, foo, B, 1]` and `[A, bar, B, 1]` would collide from  sharing the `[B, 1]` key

Comment: I asked this question more directly here with an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510012/it-appears-that-entities-in-datastore-use-their-ancestor-key-as-part-of-their-lo